# Can't import OrbitControls.js with Three.js

Tags: javascript

I'm going over three.js, and found this example.
https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-load-gltf.html
Unfortunately, I keep getting this error for all three imports when I run it locally using Flask.

```
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
```

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I've looked high and low for solutions, and can't find any.

I've also tried to run the three imports with script tags.

```
<script src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/three/build/three.js')}}"></script>
<script type="module" src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js')}}"></script>
<script type="module" src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js')}}"></script>
```

This works, but when I try the code below, I get:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: OrbitControls is not defined`

```
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
controls.update();
```

Also, if I try either for GLTFLoader, I get an error.

```
const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
```

or

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
```

Any idea how I can solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to say that your script tag is of type `module`. So what you need is something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.module.js';
      import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
      import {GLTFLoader} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```